# MD array: Add additional array if value isn't found

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, google-visualization

I am currently trying to use Google tables to generate a report based of information am pulling from my MYSQL Database.

The problem is there is 5 Header Values: `['Call Disposition', 'Answered', 'Busy', 'No Answer','Failed']`

But the problem is the data being pulled from the DB is pretty much going to have 3 out of the 4 values which will define my Google chart header, the reason for this is if "Failed" is found and only one value has it I get the following error from Google Charts: `Uncaught Error: Row 0 has 4 columns, but must have 5`

Just for some clarity on the DB, the values are being automatically inserted based on what happens to a call, and not all calls are going to fail.

Only a few instances will have the value failed, so I am trying to develop a way that if it isn't found for a particular number then add that extra array.

For example this is how it looks currently based on what am pulling out of the DB and shoved into an MD Array:

```
[ [ 'ANSWERED', '477', 728 ],
  [ 'BUSY', '477', 48 ],
  [ 'NO ANSWER', '477', 277 ],
  [ 'ANSWERED', '488', 953 ],
  [ 'BUSY', '488', 9 ],
  [ 'FAILED', '488', 1 ],
  [ 'NO ANSWER', '488', 126 ] ]
```

So if say there was no array with a number that does not have a Failed disposition add it but set the value to 0 like so every time it isn't found for each number:

```
[ [ 'ANSWERED', '477', 728 ],
  [ 'BUSY', '477', 48 ],
  [ 'FAILED', '477', 0 ],
  [ 'NO ANSWER', '477', 277 ],
  [ 'ANSWERED', '488', 953 ],
  [ 'BUSY', '488', 9 ],
  [ 'FAILED', '488', 1 ],
  [ 'NO ANSWER', '488', 126 ] ]
```

The code I have right now is the following:

```
    function SQLReportAgentCalls() {
    valueArr = [];
    connection2.query({
      sql : 'select disposition, src, COUNT(*) from cdr WHERE src="477" or src="488" GROUP BY src, disposition',
      timeout : 40000
    }, function (error, results, rows, fields) {
        console.log("-----------REPORTS------------------------");
        for(i in results){
                var dipo = results[i]['disposition'];
                var src = results[i]['src'];
                var count = results[i]['COUNT(*)'];

                if(dipo === "FAILED" && count){
                var chanar = new Array(dipo,src,count);
                valueArr.push(chanar);
                }

                else if(src && count === null && dipo !== "FAILED" ){
                var chanar = new Array("FAILED",src,0);
                valueArr.push(chanar);
                }

                else{
                var chanar = new Array(dipo,src,count);
                valueArr.push(chanar);
                }
        }
        console.log(valueArr);
        console.log("---------------------------------------------------");
        SQLReport();
    });
  }
```

Client side code generating the report:

```
//This generates the report(Google Chart) based on the information that has been pulled from the CDR table server side.
    socket.on("SQL", function (valueArr) {
        google.charts.load('current', {
            packages : ['corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMaterial);
        var data = valueArr;
        function x(data) {
            var r = [],
            temp;
            valueArr.forEach(function (a, i) {
                if (!(i % 3)) {
                    temp = [a[1]];
                    r.push(temp);
                }
                temp.push(a[2]);
            });
            return r;
        }
        function drawMaterial() {

            result = [['Call Disposition', 'Answered', 'Busy', 'No Answer', 'Failed']].concat(x(valueArr));
            console.log(result);
            var options = {
                title : 'Call Disposition',
                hAxis : {
                    title : 'Agents',
                    minValue : 0,
                },
                vAxis : {
                    title : 'Disposition Number'
                },
                isStacked : true
            };
            var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
            var material = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
            material.draw(chartdata, options);
        }
    });
```

Is this possible? Am not sure if Google Charts offers the option to automatically add values if they do not exist so this seems like the only way I could think of to resolve the issue.

Comment: For better performance, change src ="477" or src = "488" to: src in("477","488")

Comment: @sagi Thank you for that tip I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the array needs to resemble this...

`['Call Disposition', 'Answered', 'Busy', 'No Answer','Failed']`

it would probably be easier to change the SQL to something like this...

```
select
  a.src,
  (select count(*) from cdr where src = a.src and disposition = 'ANSWERED'),
  (select count(*) from cdr where src = a.src and disposition = 'BUSY'),
  (select count(*) from cdr where src = a.src and disposition = 'NO ANSWER'),
  (select count(*) from cdr where src = a.src and disposition = 'FAILED')
from
  cdr a
where
  a.src in ("477", "488")
group by
  a.src
```

Comment: The array already resembles that the SQL query is not the issue its when am then sticking that into an array, failed is not going to be there for all src numbers, I have added client side code for clarity. Those values are hard coded as they wont change.

Comment: I'm suggesting changing the SQL to eliminate the need to manipulate the data on the client -- the SQL I have provided will include a zero in the 'FAILED' column if it doesn't exist...

Comment: is there a more efficient way it seems to be quite slow for me due to the amount of records compared to what I was using before